# Reinitialize a jQuery plugin by removing its related DOM presence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [jQuery Tokeninput plugin](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) and it does its work well. Though the thing I am missing is a way to reinitialize it with new tags data. I can't just run something like `$('.mytokeninput').tokenInput('init', new_tags_list);` on an existing tokeninput-enabled field. I use workaround - I clear the wrapper div of `.mytokeninput`, add a new `.mytokeninput` to it and then run a new tokenInput instance on it.

I wonder if this is a very bad idea and I should do it differently or if it's more or less acceptable from the best practices point of view.  Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
$( input ).tokenInput( 'clear' );
// where input is a reference to your text field
```

It clears all tokens from the tokeninput.

Comment: Then how do I reinit it with a new set of tags? I don't need them to be added to the current visible input, but just to become available for searching with autosuggest.

Comment: @SergeyBasharov You wrote that in your question: `.tokenInput('init', new_tags_list)`

Comment: it was just my suggestion how it could look, but then I checked source file and found init method there though I couldn't find it in the help page for the plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers comment about the init did not work for me.  The way that I am doing it is as follows: (coffeescript)

```
# remove the tokens input list that it creates everytime the item is initialized
$('.token-input-dropdown').remove()    
$('.token-input-list').remove()

# initialize the list
$('#tokenList').tokenInput(
  [{'id':'1', 'name':'first'}]
)
```

Not ideal to have to remove the div, but this absolutely works for me. (Also, if you use a different theme, then you have to change $('.token-input-dropdown') to $('.token-input-dropdown-facebook') or whatever theme you are using.